# $3x^2+ 5xy -2y^2 = 12$ is a hyperbola. Prove the major axis lies on $y = \tan(22.5)x$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

We have
$$3x^2+ 5xy -2y^2 = 12.$$

Prove the major axis lies on $y = \tan(22.5)x$.

The hyperbola is a rotation of $22.5$ degrees of a normal hyperbola, which I think is why the slope of the major axis is $\tan(22.5)$.

I don't know how to prove this though.

***Edit:***

I figured out that the original equation can be rewritten as $x^2/4 + 5xy/12 - y^2/6 = 1$, so the non rotated hyperbola is $x^2/4 - y^2/6 = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
3x^2 + 5xy - 2y^2 = 0\\
(3x - y)(x + 2y) = 0\\
$$

So the lines $y = 3x$ and $y = \frac{-1}{2} x$ are asymptotes. Bisect these by finding the angles each make with the positive x-axis.